# execute zoho page sense custom tracking event from zapier

Tags: zapier, zoho

I have a tracking pixel and a custom event fire. I cannot seem to get it to work in zapier javascript code. The pixek needs to load, (i dont know if i should use the syncronous or asyncronous version) then the 2 lines of custom event code need to run. I dont know how to format/syntax this to work in zapier code.

```
Page sense custom events
// pixel-syncronous
<script src="https://cdn.pagesense.io/js/fitboss/d4999e900d8f4c78b749ee42a84bcd1f.js"></script>

// pixel-asyncronous
<script type="text/javascript">(function(w,s){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=true;e.src="https://cdn.pagesense.io/js/fitboss/d4999e900d8f4c78b749ee42a84bcd1f.js";var x=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(e,x);})(window,"script");</script>

// custom event
window.pagesense = window.pagesense || [];
window.pagesense.push(['trackEvent', 'Video Played']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted won't work in `Code by Zapier`. It runs using Node.js (made for the backend), but the code you posted is meant to be run in the browser (note the HTML tags and use of `window`).

You have a couple of options:

1. If there's a web API, use that instead. You can make HTTP requests from `Code by Zapier` or use `Webhooks by Zapier`.
2. Otherwise, look for a `Node.js` package that works with PageSense. You can wrap that in a simple [custom integration](https://developer.zapier.com/) that can run more advanced JS code.

Comment: xavdid, thanks for your response. it appears there is no API or webhook for page sense. nor is there a built in zapier action for page sense. I guess im stuck with option 2. I have a vague sense of what you getting at but can you give me a starting point on where to begin with that? as far as "a Node.js package that works with PageSense" ?Thx

Comment: I was hoping the [PageSense developer page](https://apitracker.io/a/zoho-pagesense) would have a node.js SDK or something, but you may be out of luck. There _must_ be some sort of web API, because that's what the JS code loaded from those `cdn.pagesense.io/js/...` links hits. Whether it's easy to use or documented is another story. Unfortunately I don't know anything about the product, so I'm afraid I can't be much more help. You might try reaching out to their support team.